# Can't loop through check boxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have the code:

```
Dim collect = New Collection()
For x As Integer = 1 To achs.Count Step 1
    Dim toAdd = TableLayoutPanel2.Controls("CheckBox" + CStr(x))
    collect.Add(toAdd)
Next
```

Where `achs` is defines as a `Collection()` with a `Count() = 109`. When the form loads it creates all 109 checkboxes and places them in `TabelLayoutPanel2`, I can't find a way to name them if they're defined via `Dim chk = New CheckBox` so I'm expecting them to be named `CheckBox1...CheckBox109`.

This question is in two parts, first I would like to know how I can specifically name the CheckBoxes that are created, secondly I would like to know if there is any way to change or fix my code to get the checkboxes `Checked` value, as it doesn't allow me to add `.Checked` to the end of the 3<sup>rd</sup> line in that code block. I am new to VBA and do not know much, so if you could be as explanatory as possible it would be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the Name property of the CheckBoxes when you create them. In the designer, you can easily do this in the properties window.
2. I think the problem is that the controls collection returns a Control object, not a Checkbox object that does have the Checked property. Change your code as follows:

   Dim toAdd = DirectCast(TableLayoutPanel2.Controls("Checkbox" + CStr(x)), Checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

1) Just use the `name` property when creating a new `CheckBox`, so when you do `Dim chk = New CheckBox` you can follow by `chk.name="checkboxname"`

2) When you create the new control (e.g. `Dim chk=New CheckBox`, follow by `chk.Checked=true`)